# Get count of array items in a JSON log file

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am working with the RDSOS log which is produced by my Aroura DB.
It is a JSON file and has a flattened array of `processList.0` ~ `processList.n`.

I have been digging through the docs to no avail. Is there a way to get the n-th processList on the fly like iteration?

```
    fields processList.length as processes
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 1
```

Comment: what about `processList.length`?

Comment: one would think, right. I have added what I used and got no return.